# STAThread error (SaveFileDialog) on a new Form

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

So basicaly i have made a login system for my program, and when a user logs it it opens up Form1. But i need the Form1 to be a STA thread.
I am getting this error in Form1:

> {"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process."}
>   In this code

```
SaveFileDialog FSave = new SaveFileDialog()
        {
            Filter = "Executable Files|*.exe",
            InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        };
        if (FSave.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)//im getting the error here
        {
        // CodeDom compiler code
        }
```

this is my Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace hwid_login_system
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Login());
        }
    }
}
```

This is how i open form Form1 in form Logins

```
private void complete()
    {
        if (loggedin && hwid)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Logged in successfully!");
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
            t.Start();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Something else went wrong..", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
public static void ThreadProc()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling FSave.ShowDialog() from another thread?

Comment: Updated how i open Form1 in form Logins

Comment: Just anwsere my own question :D

added `t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);` to run it as a STA thread

Comment: I do that all the time.  ;->

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me a lot, more than current @tHand 's answer. Please consider expanding it to an answer, that would be much more visible than just a comment, and we will be able to say "thank you" by upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling FSave.ShowDialog() from within your second thread, you will get this error. You should always open your windows forms from within you main application thread.

Consider calling a delegate to show you dialog from your thread rather then opening the form directly.